# Android edit text with custom shape

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-shape

How can I edit text shape like this.

[image]

I mean that right rounded corners and exact same shape. As I understood 9 patch doesn't help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9 patch will be best way in your situation, create 9 patch and set it as background of your `EditText`.

Here i am giving you sample image, you can try with it.

[image]

```
editText.setBackground(R.drawable.edt_bg);
```

Answer (score 1):

This ninepatches will help you. just apply this ninepatch images as backgroud of the editText

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create background image for your `EditText`. For the other layout, you have to create layout which will look like this. Its not the exact xml but showing you the idea.

```
<RelativeLayout layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="50dp"> 
       <EditText layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@drawable/editTextBackground" layout_alignParentLeft="true" layout_marginLeft="10dp">

       <ImageView layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"
                  centerVertical="true" marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/smily" />

       <ImageView layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"
                  centerVertical="true" 
                  alignRight="@id/editTExt"
                  android:background="@drawable/camera" />

       <ImageView layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"
                  centerVertical="true" marginLeft="15dp"
                  alignParentRight="true"
                  android:background="@drawable/mic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this gives you the idea.